# How to draw ligands with different hapticities

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

In organometallic chemistry it's common to draw ligands that are not bound atom to atom. Common examples are ferrocene:

[image]

or Zeisse's salt:

[image]

Does anyone have a strategy for approaching structures such as these?

For the alkene bond, one approach would be
`\chemfig{M-([2,0.5]=)([6,0.5]=}`
but this has the bond from the metal extending to the center of the double bond, rather than stop just before it.

I'm looking more for a general approach than a solution to these particular compounds.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not aware of a truly general approach. I solve these kinds of bonds by using invisible bonds `-[,,,,draw=none]` for placing atoms or determining access points for other bonds.

Ferrocene and similar compounds are not quite easy with `chemfig` and my approach is even less general. So far the only way I know is to draw them from scratch (but then I do not need to draw metallocenes very often (or ever)). Here's a try I recently used as an [answer on chemieonline.de](http://www.chemieonline.de/forum/showthread.php?t=198519):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setcrambond{3pt}{}{}
\begin{document}

\chemfig{
  ?[a]>[:18,.8]-[:108,.8]-[4]
    (
      -[:-40,.65,,,draw=none]@{r1}-[2,,,,dotted]
      Fe
      -[2,,,,dotted]@{r2}-[:-130,.7,,,draw=none]
      ?[b]-[,,,,line width=3.5pt]>[:72,.8]-[:162,.8]-[:-162,.8]?[b,4]
    )
  -[:-108,.8]?[a,4]}
\chemmove{
  \draw (r1) ellipse (15pt and 8pt);
  \draw (r2) ellipse (15pt and 8pt);
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The values need adjusting of course (I was being lazy) but the principle should be clear. What I've done here is the following: I drew the cp rings using `chemfig`'s `?` hook and marked the center (or actually only somewhere near) by using the `@{<nodename>}` syntax. These nodes then are accessed via `\chemmove` (which basically is a wrapper for `\tikz[remember picture,overlay]`) to draw the ellipses. This needs a least two compilations.

The second one's easier. I just use an invisible bond like I said above. This should also work for other similar compounds:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemmacros}% for formal charges
\definesubmol{inv}{-[,,,,draw=none]}
\begin{document}

\chemfig{
  H>[:-10]C(<:[:60]H)
   (-[:-14.5,2,,,draw=none]Pt(-[4,1.8])(<[:-120]Cl)(<:[:60]Cl|^{\fminus})-Cl)
   =[6]
  C(<[:-110]H)<:[:-20]H
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It's becoming clear to me that I should familiarize myself with TikZ. The `\chemmove` command is new to me. I really appreciate such an elaborate answer.

Comment: `\chemmove` is described in the `chemfig` manual in the section about electon movement. And yes, since `chemfig` uses TikZ internally it often helps if one knows the basics of TikZ :)

Answer (score 6):

[image: Ferroceno Metanol]

Hi, if you don´t wont to make double compilation, I draw a Ferrocene Methanol molecule with `\chemfig` and `\tikz` that requieres only one compilation. Here is the code.

Regards.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig,xstring}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,arrows,positioning,graphs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%Lineas de ayuda, cuadricula
%\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (6,4);

%Anillo Superior
\node at (0.78,2.95) {\chemfig{
        <[:-25,1.176]
        (   
            -[0,0.01,,,line width=6.1pt,shorten <=-1.5pt,shorten >=-1.5pt]           
            >[:25,1.176] 
            -[:135,0.8] (
                    %Metanol
                    -[:30,1]-[:-35,1]OH
                    )
            -[180,1]
            -[:-135,0.8]
        )}};

%Anillo Inferior
\node at (0,0.3){\chemfig{
            -[:25,1.176]
        (            
            -[:-25,1.176]
            <[:-135,0.8]
            -[180,,,,line width=4.8pt,shorten <=-2.2pt,shorten >=-2.2pt]
            >[:135,0.8]            
        )}};

\draw [dashed]  (0,1.75) -- (0,2.9);
\draw [dashed]  (0,0.3) -- (0,1.3);
\draw (0,0.3) ellipse (0.75cm and 0.35cm);
\draw (0,2.85) ellipse (0.75cm and 0.35cm);
\node at (0,1.5) {\Large Fe};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use

```
\usepackage{chemfig}
  \setatomsep{14.4pt}
  \setdoublesep{2.6pt}
  \setbondstyle{line width=0.6pt}
  \setcrambond{2.0pt}{0.6pt}{2.5pt}
  \setbondoffset{1.6pt}
  \setarrowdefault{,1.0,}
  \renewcommand*\printatom[1]{{\fontfamily{arial}\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}}

\chemfig
{
  <[:303.51,0.4476]@{r5}{}%
  -[:0,,,,line width=2pt]@{r6}{}%
  >[:56.49,0.4476]%
  -[:164.82,0.7741]%
  -[:195.18,0.7741]%
  -[:355,0.7472,,,draw=none]@{r1}{}-[2,0.70]%
  Fe
  -[2,0.85]@{r2}{\,}-[:175,0.7472,,,draw=none]
  <[:303.51,0.4476]@{r3}{}%
  -[:0,,,,line width=2pt]@{r4}{}%
  >[:56.49,0.4476](-X)%
  -[:164.82,0.7741]%
  -[:195.18,0.7741]
}
\chemmove
{
  \draw (r1) ellipse (6pt and 2pt);
  \draw (r2) ellipse (6pt and 2pt);
  \fill (r3) ellipse (1pt and 1.1pt);
  \fill (r4) ellipse (1pt and 1.1pt);
  \fill (r5) ellipse (1pt and 1.1pt);
  \fill (r6) ellipse (1pt and 1.1pt);
}
\chemfig
{
  -[:-303.51,0.4476]%
  -[:0,,,,]%
  -[:-56.49,0.4476](-[:-10]Z)%
  <[:-164.82,0.7741]@{r5}{}%
  >[:-195.18,0.7741]%
  -[:10,0.7472,,,draw=none]@{r1}{}-[2,0.70]%
  Fe
  -[2,0.85]@{r2}{\,}-[:175,0.7472,,,draw=none]
  <[:303.51,0.4476]@{r3}{}%
  -[:0,,,,line width=2pt]@{r4}{}%
  >[:56.49,0.4476](-Y)%
  -[:164.82,0.7741]%
  -[:195.18,0.7741]
}
\chemmove
{
  \draw (r1) ellipse (6pt and 2pt);
  \draw (r2) ellipse (6pt and 2pt);
  \fill (r3) ellipse (1pt and 1.1pt);
  \fill (r4) ellipse (1pt and 1.1pt);
  \fill (r5) ellipse (1pt and 1.3pt);
}
\chemfig
{
  -[:-303.51,0.4476]%
  -[:0,,,,]%
  -[:-56.49,0.4476](-[:-10]X)%
  <[:-164.82,0.7741]@{r5}{}%
  >[:-195.18,0.7741]%
  -[:10,0.7472,,,draw=none]@{r1}{}-[2,0.70]%
  Fe
  -[2,0.85]@{r2}{\,}-[:175,0.7472,,,draw=none]
  <[:303.51,0.4476]@{r3}{}%
  -[:0,,,,line width=2pt]@{r4}{}%
  >[:56.49,0.4476](
    -[:0]
    -[:-303.51,0.4476]%
    -[:0,,,,]%
    -[:-56.49,0.4476](-[:-10]Y)%
    <[:-164.82,0.7741]@{r10}{}%
    >[:-195.18,0.7741]%
    -[:10,0.7472,,,draw=none]@{r6}{}-[2,0.70]%
    Fe
    -[2,0.85]@{r7}{\,}-[:175,0.7472,,,draw=none]
    <[:303.51,0.4476]@{r8}{}%
    -[:0,,,,line width=2pt]@{r9}{}%
    >[:56.49,0.4476]
    -[:164.82,0.7741]%
    -[:195.18,0.7741]
  )%
  -[:164.82,0.7741]%
  -[:195.18,0.7741]
}
\chemmove
{
  \draw (r1)  ellipse (6pt and 2pt);
  \draw (r2)  ellipse (6pt and 2pt);
  \fill (r3)  ellipse (1pt and 1.1pt);
  \fill (r4)  ellipse (1pt and 1.1pt);
  \fill (r5)  ellipse (1pt and 1.3pt);
  \draw (r6)  ellipse (6pt and 2pt);
  \draw (r7)  ellipse (6pt and 2pt);
  \fill (r8)  ellipse (1pt and 1.1pt);
  \fill (r9)  ellipse (1pt and 1.1pt);
  \fill (r10) ellipse (1pt and 1.3pt);
}
```

which looks like this:

[image: FcX and 1,1'-FcYZ]

It is inspired by the way ChemDraw draws metallocenes and it is more or less ACS-Style.

You may have to compile the document twice.

Answer (score 0):

I made a macro (based on the answer above)
It works OK with [12pt]{article}; switching to 10pt shifts the rings a little bit. Also some shifts when the revtex style is used instead of article

```
%/** 
%  *  @author Vladislav Malyshkin mal@gromco.com
%  *  @version $Id: ferrocenemacro.tex,v 1.1 2020/12/10 12:37:34 mal Exp $
%  */
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true]{microtype}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,arrows,positioning,graphs,calc}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78275/how-to-draw-ligands-with-different-hapticities/78309#78309

\begin{document}




\begin{tikzpicture}

%Lineas de ayuda, cuadricula
%\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (6,4);

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% \ferrocenetwoargs macro
\newcommand{\ferrocenetwoargs}[2]{
    \chemfig{(
        @{aleft}<[:-25,1.176]
        (   
            -[0,0.01,,,line width=6.1pt,shorten <=-1.5pt,shorten >=-1.5pt]           
            >[:25,1.176]@{aright}({#1})
            -[:135,0.8]
            -[180,1]
            -[:-135,0.8]
            ))
            % lower ring position
            -[-90,2.2,,,draw=none]
            (
             @{bleft}-[:25,1.176]
        (            
            -[:-25,1.176]@{bright}({#2})
            <[:-135,0.8]
            -[180,,,,line width=4.8pt,shorten <=-2.2pt,shorten >=-2.2pt]
            >[:135,0.8]
        )
            )
    }
    \chemmove{
%      \draw (aleft) -- (aright);
%      \draw (bleft) -- (bright);
      \coordinate (ca) at ($0.5*(aleft)+0.5*(aright)+(0,0.13)$);
      \coordinate (cb) at ($0.5*(bleft)+0.5*(bright)+(0,-0.03)$);
      \draw (cb) ellipse (0.75cm and 0.35cm);
      \draw (ca) ellipse (0.75cm and 0.35cm);
      \draw [dashed,-]  (ca) --  node[fill=white] {\Large Fe} (cb);
}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% end of \ferrocenetwoargs macro

% plot an example
\node at (3,2) {
  \ferrocenetwoargs{-CH_3}{-[:10,1]-[:-35,1]OH}
  \ferrocenetwoargs{-CH_2-CH_3}{}
  \ferrocenetwoargs{}{-CH_2-CH_3}

};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: how it looks]