# ChemFig - Interaction with aromatic ring/delocalised notation for isomers

Tags: chemfig

OK, as it seems neither the manual nor google find an answer, maybe "you" as a community have an idea.

*Can I draw an aromatic ring with a delocalised bond (attached to the ring) in ChemFig?*

One example would be the anion interaction in Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_interaction#Anion_.CF.80-interactions

In my case I am interested in representing the isomers of cresols using a single molecule notation which is commonly done by showing a bond between the OH and the aromatic ring.

Not sure if this shows for the non-academics, a figure in a paper. The last molecule is a cresol and the type of molecule I'm interested in, ideally with a proper aromatic ring:
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/enhanced/figures/doi/10.1002/cphc.200700563#figure-viewer-sch1

For those that want a minimum working example, here is a a single cresol in LaTex/ChemFig:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}%

%\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setatomsep{2em}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
%\sisetup{range-phrase=-,range-units=single}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{
**6(-(-OH)---(-)--)
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at [How to draw ligands with different hapticities](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78275/)

Comment: Looks messy - but I guess it should work. Something for my afternoon/evening I guess... Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

With a recent version of `chemfig`, you can make use of the node name `cyclecenter<n>` (where `<n>` is the serial number of the relevant ring) in a `\chemmove` command to refer to the center of a ring drawn in the previous `\chemfig` command. This way, you can reproduce the molecule like in the paper you refer to. With a little Ti*k*Z magic, you can "break" the ring at the relevant position where the line crosses it:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setchemfig{atom sep=2em}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{
    *6(-=-(-CH_3)=-=)
}
\chemmove{
    \draw[-] (cyclecenter1) -- +(1,0) 
        node[right, inner sep=2pt] {\printatom{OH}};
}

\bigskip

\chemfig{
    *6(-=-(-CH_3)=-=)
}
\chemmove{
    \draw[-, preaction={draw, white, line width=3pt}] 
        (cyclecenter1) -- +(1,0) 
        node[right, inner sep=2pt] {\printatom{OH}};
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You can also set different Ti*k*Z options to the `\chemfig` drawing using the `atom style` option, such as `yscale` to achieve an effect similar to that of the molecule in the linked Wikipedia article (if you don't want to use cram bonds like in the [answers linked in the comments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78275/)):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig, mathtools}
\setchemfig{atom sep=2em}

\begin{document}
\rule{0pt}{1.5cm} % add some space

\chemfig[atom style={yscale=0.5}]{
    *6(-=-=-=)
}
\chemmove{
    \draw[-, densely dotted, thick] (cyclecenter1) -- +(0,1) 
        node[above, inner sep=2pt] {\printatom{X^{\mathrlap{-}}}};
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here as well, you could use the `preaction` trick to "break" the circle:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig, mathtools}
\setchemfig{atom sep=2em}

\begin{document}
\rule{0pt}{1.5cm} % add some space

\chemfig[atom style={yscale=0.5}]{
    *6(-=-=-=)
}
\chemmove{
    \draw[-, densely dotted, thick, preaction={draw, white, line width=3pt}] 
        (cyclecenter1) -- +(0,1) 
        node[above, inner sep=2pt] {\printatom{X^{\mathrlap{-}}}};
}
\end{document}
```

[image]