# Using chemfig, how to make individual bonds longer or no longer visible

Tags: chemfig

I am currently trying to draw the structure of a complex for a project

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{ La(-[:0](**5(-(-)-(-)-(-)-(-)-)))(-[:120](**5(-(-)-(-)-(-)-(-)-)))(-[:240](**5(-(-)-(-)-(-)-(-)-)))   }

\end{document}
```

I was hoping to either extend the bonds between the cyclopentadienide rings and the La so that the bond lies in the centre of all of the rings or just to make these bonds appear invisible.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please add a sketch of the desired output?

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, I assume that this is (close to) what you want to draw:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2nMQ.png

Comment: [How to draw ligands with different hapticities](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78275/134144) might also be interesting.

Comment: leandriis Something like that picture is perfect and thank you for the link

Answer (score 2):

Making bonds invisible is easy by adding `draw=none` to the corresponding tikz arguments of the bonds. This way you could also make them dotted or coloured or both…

Extending the bonds requires a little bit of math for the correct length but in the end is also simple by adding additional bonds:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{
  La(-[:0,,,,draw=none](**5(-(-)-(-)-(-)-(-)-)))
    (-[:120,,,,draw=none](**5(-(-)-(-)-(-)-(-)-)))
    (-[:240,,,,draw=none](**5(-(-)-(-)-(-)-(-)-)))
}

\bigskip

\chemfig{
  La(-[:0](**5((-[:0,.851])-(-)-(-)-(-)-(-)-)))
    (-[:120](**5((-[:120,.851])-(-)-(-)-(-)-(-)-)))
    (-[:240](**5((-[:240,.851])-(-)-(-)-(-)-(-)-)))
}

\end{document}
```

[image]