# Using chemfig to draw complex ring structures

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig, chemistry, chemmacros

So I am trying to recreate the following reactions with `chemfig` but I am somewhat getting lost on what to do. I was able to start off with a general structure shown below. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig,xstring}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,arrows,positioning,graphs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0.15,-0.2) {\chemfig{
        <[:-25,1.176]
        (   
            -[0,0.01,,,line width=6.1pt,shorten <=-1.5pt,shorten >=-1.5pt]           
            (-[:225,1]H)(-[:320,1]CCl_3)>[:25,1.176]
            -[:135,0.8] 
            -[180,1]
            -[:-135,0.8]
        )}};

\node at (0,2.85){\chemfig[double bond sep=0.3em]{
            -[:25,1.176]
        (            
            -[:-25,1.176]
            <[:-135,0.8]
            -[180,,,,line width=4.8pt,shorten <=-2.2pt,shorten >=-2.2pt]
            >[:135,0.8]            
        )}};

\draw [dashed]  (0,1.75) -- (0,2.9);
\draw [dashed]  (0,0.3) -- (0,1.3);
\draw (0,0.3) ellipse (0.75cm and 0.35cm);
\draw (0,2.85) ellipse (0.75cm and 0.35cm);
\node at (0,1.5) {\Large Co};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78275/134144  could be interesting